# Earliest allowed since date

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the number of likes a page has until a specific date. I've tried not including the `since` parameter; but this gives 'An unknown error has occurred.' I've tried setting the `since` parameter to 0; but that give and 'Unsupported operation' error.

So I'm wondering what the earliest/lowest since value can be, I've tried some for various previous years, but always seem to the 'Unsupported operation' error.

I'm wondering if it's related to when the page was created, which I think was 2011-07-19 but that date doesn't seem to work either.

Anybody have any idea of how to do this?

edit: I'm using the /insights endpoint and various of the other endpoints which can go onto the end of that

Comment: Which endpoint are you using?

Comment: @Tobi I've updated the question above

Answer (score 0):

You need to use unix timestamps when you're trying to use `since` and `until` fields!

So, for example

```
GET /{page_id}/insights?since=1311073200&until=1311591600
```

to get the week from 2011-07-19 to 2011-07-25.

I think there's no way of recognizing the earliest possible date, except trying to lower the `since` parameter day by day and stopping once you reach the error message stated.

Comment: I am using unix timestamps for these parameters. I don't think that cycling through all the dates until I get the error is an acceptable solution as it will make far too many API calls.

Comment: Well, I don't think there's another solution sadly, because the creation date of a Page is not available via an API afaik. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page/ and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page

Comment: So the earliest since date allowed is the creation date of the page?